# Trying to get a hand on inheritance and super

Tags: java, oop

I am trying to really understand how inheritance and the super keyword work.

I have the following 4 classes:

People class:

```
public class People {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person people[] = new Person[4];
        people[0] = new Teacher("Anna-Belle", 37, 6);
        people[1] = new Teacher("John McGil", 43, 12);
        people[2] = new Student("Jason Blue", 25, 17);
        people[3] = new Student("Alice Grad", 22, 34);

        // let's print student's credits
        // and teacher's courses taught

        for (int i=0; i < people.length; i++) {
            Person p = people[i];
            if (p instanceof Teacher) {
                Teacher t = (Teacher) p;
                System.out.println("Teacher #" + t);
            } else if (p instanceof Student) {
                Student s = (Student) p;
                System.out.println("Student #" + s);
            } else { };
        }

    }
}
```

Person class:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    int age;

    Person(String name, int age)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

    public String toString() {
        return " "  +   super.toString() + " (Person): " + name + ", " + age;
    }
```

Teacher class:

```
class Teacher extends Person {

    Teacher(String n, int a, int c)
        {
            super(n,a);
            coursesTaught = c;
        }

    public String toString() {
        return super.toString()
            + ", (Teacher): " + coursesTaught;
    }

    int coursesTaught;
}
```

Student class:

```
class Student extends Person {

    Student(String n, int a, int c)
        { 
            super(n,a);
            creditsCompleted = c;
        }

    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() 
            + ", (Student): " + creditsCompleted;
    }

    int creditsCompleted;
}
```

What I don't understand is how the super keyword works I guess. for instance how come the super.toString() in the teacher class knows what to take and convert to a string??

Actually thinking about it, I understand what super does. It says to go to the up a level to the superclass. I guess I am confused as to what happens when these 2 are combined? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Doesn't it become clear when you run this? It just calls the `toString` method on the superclass.

Comment: What do you mean by the 2nd question "I guess I am confused as to what happens when these 2 are combined?"

Comment: I mistakenly thought the .tostring() method was a keyword type of method. I didnt think it was just calling the .tostring method from the superclass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right: `super` goes up one level and invokes the toString() method on the parent class.

What might not be obvious, if you are new to Java, is that every class inherits from `Object`. Every class that does not explicitly extend something, implicitly extends `Object`. So, in effect, your `Person` class looks like this (BTW, this still compiles):

```
public class Person extends Object {
  ...
}
```

For a more visual representation go to your `Teacher` class in Eclipse and press `Ctrl` + `T`

[image: Hierarchy as presented by Eclipse]

Therefore, when you call `toString()` on a `Teacher` instance, `toString()` is invoked on `Person`. There another `super.toString()` call is made. The direct parent of `Person` is `Object` thus the default `toString()` on the `Object` class is invoked, which looks like this:

```
public String toString() {
  return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

That is where the first part of your output comes from. The part before the @, is the **runtime type** of the instance. The hex string after the @ is a hash representing the object instance, which is usually derived from the memory location:

`Teacher #`**Teacher@5d0385c1** `(Person): Anna-Belle, 37, (Teacher): 6`

It is the **runtime type** that determines which method will be called. E.g.

```
Person person = new Teacher("ABC", 37, 6);
System.out.println(person);
```

will print this:

```
Teacher@4fe5e2c3 (Person): ABC, 37, (Teacher): 6
```

Even though the compile time type is `Person` at runtime the `toString()` on `Teacher` is invoked.

Comment: I think you really got to the root of my problems understanding this here. When you say every class inherits from object I am still confused. In this case the person class is inheriting from what exactly?

Comment: Where is that default toString() method coming from that is being called on the object class?

Comment: I feel like I am close to getting it but yet so far.. This is painful. Why is the @5d0385c1 printing?

Comment: Ok I get what you are saying now I didnt realize every class extends object. Why does the "default toString() implementation" come from though?

Comment: I completely understand now. Thank you very much for spelling that out for me. I somehow thing it was important to understand well.

Comment: I tried to answer all your questions in edits. You might want to have a look at the source code of the Object class. The comments there are very thorough and insightful.

Comment: Yep Just want to say thanks again! You really helped me successfully understand.

Answer (score 0):

`toString()` in `Teacher` class operates on fields available in `Teacher` class -- the only field specific to `Teacher` is `coursesTaught`. The same logic applies to call `super.toString()` in `Teacher.toString` -- `super` for Teacher is `Person`, so `Person.toString()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

super is used to access any of the immediate parent's members or methods. Note that using super you cannot access the Grand Parents members or methods as super.super,,,,.

Answer (score 0):

he write super.toString() because there is a method called toString() in each classing and teacher class has his own toString() method (because it declared in Object calss and each Java class is inheriting Object Class).

but in the example he need to take the parent toString() method so he has to write it in this way.